# Python Math - Floating with financial output comes out incorrect

Tags: python-3.x

In a small portion of code for a retail auditing calculator, I'm attempting to allow the input of a retail value and multiply it by up to 2 entered quantities The expected (intended) result is $X*Y=$Z.

I've attempted to modify the code a couple of says and seem to be stuck on how this math is (isn't) working correctly.

I've attempted a number of different configurations in the code and the most I've achieved is the following:

```
#Retail value of item, whole number (i.e. $49.99 entered as 4999)
rtlVAL = input("Retail Value: ")

#Quantity of Items - can be multiplied for full stack items, default if no entry is '1'
qt1 = float(input("Quantity 1: ")) #ex. 4
qt2 = float(input("Quantity 2: ") or "1") #ex " "

#Convert the Retail Value to finacial format (i.e 4999 to $49.99)
rtl = float("{:.2}".format (rtlVAL))

# Screen Output
qtyVAL = int(qt1)*int(qt2)
print("$" + str(qtyVAL*rtl))
```

The entered values are:
Retail Value: 4999
Quantity 1: 4
Quantity 2: (blank)

The expected performance is 4999 * 4 * (because no entry defaults to value of 1) and the *expected* result is *$199.96*

The result of this code is *$196.0*, so not only is it the *wrong conclusion* but it's *missing the two decimal places*.

I'm not entirely certain why the math comes up wrong in context to expectation.

What am I missing here?

---

On line 9, I've tried the following:

`rtl = float("{:.2f}".format (rtlVAL))`

`rtl = int("{:.2f}".format (rtlVAL))`

The return was

> ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

if I change line 13 to:

```
print("$" + float(qtyVAL*rtl))
```

I get

> TypeError: must be str, not float

using  either of the prior alterations in conjunction with the latter will return the *ValueError:*

---

Python 3.4 and 3.6

I did search a few other SO questions regarding Python, Math, Floating point, and formatting but the questions were looking for and presenting something far more advances and entangled than this so i wasn't able to glean an answer to make a contextual application or it applied mainly to Python 2.7 wherein some of the code such as `raw input()` is simply `input()` and altered by `int(input())`in Python 3.x to step out of `str` value (as far as I understand for this purpose.

I did not see this as a duplicate, but if I missed something in that I do apologize - it isn't intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mess around with number formats:

```
rtl = float(rtlVAL)/100
```

Just divide the retail value by 100 to get the dollar value

EDIT:

Incidentally, the reason it was coming up with 196 was because your number format was taking the first two digits of `rtlVAL` - 49 in your case - and then multiplying by that.

Comment: Thank you. I wondered why it was evaluating to 196 and was looking in to that when you answered. 

I guess I was getting hung up on ensuring that the number formatting was correct that I missed the more obvious solution.

Comment: I spent like two hours yesterday trying to work out why my variable `requirement` was returning `null`.  It turns out I'd declared is as `requirements`.  Until you've done that you're not allowed to feel stupid.  Glad I could help.

Comment: sounds like a few episodes I've had with VBA and Excel. I guess it happens to us all.